# Datamapper: Save more than one value in a relationship

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper

I’m totally new at CI and Datamapper and i wanna do a very simple thing, i think.

I have a database with 3 tables

```
 courses
 students
 students_courses
```

I’m using this models

Student

```
        <?php
           class Student extends DataMapper {
           var $has_many = array('course');
          }
```

Courses

```
        <?php
          class Course extends DataMapper {
          var $has_many = array('student');
        }
```

And this controller to add students and select their courses

Students Controller

```
          function add(){

            $estudiante = new Student();
            $estudiante->name = $this->input->post('nombre');
            $estudiante->save();

            $user = new Student();
            $curso = new Course();


            $user->get_by_name($estudiante->name);
            $curso->get_by_name($this->input->post('curso'));

            $user->save($curso);

            $this->load->view('student/confirm');

          }
```

and, finally, this form on the view

```
    <p> 
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    </p>

    <p> 
        <label for="nombre">Curso:</label> 
        <select multiple name="curso" id="curso">
            <?php 

            foreach($course_list as $item) {

            echo "<option value='$item->name'>" . "$item->name" . "</option>";
             }

             ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">


<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

All works great when i want to save ONE value from the select list….but, what i have to do to save MORE than one value?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem could be related with database modelling. You need to specify an many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Course`.

Also, you need to iterate over `$this->input->post('curso')` to get all Courses an Student may have. Something like this:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('curso') as $entry)
{
    $curso = new Course();
    $curso->get_by_name($entry);
    $user->save($curso);
}
```

I don't have experience with DataMapper, but I think your problem can be solved this way :)